# should I explicitly define a module in a namespaced controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've seem code samples like this in Rails tutorials:

```
module Api
  class UsersController
    # ... 
  end
end
```

And like this:

```
class Api::UsersController
  # ...
end
```

Both code samples seems to be working fine, even though RubyMine IDE is giving me a warning that the module is not defined in the 2nd example. Could you guys explain? Thanks a bunch

Comment: I don't know much about RubyMine, but these class declarations are equivalent, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the code snippets would declare a module Api with the UsersController inside of it.

The difference between the declarations however is that in the first snippet, the lexical scope is set to the Api module. Let's say you have a class `Api::User`. In the first snippet, you may omit the module:

```
module Api
  class UsersController
    def action
      @user = User.first # #<Api::User>
    end
  end
end
```

Since the lexical scope is set to the Api module, that's also where Ruby first searches for the class.

In the second snippet however, you do need to be explicit about the namespace, or otherwise it may be unable to resolve the constant:

```
class Api::UsersController
  def action
    @user = User.first # #<NameError: uninitialized constant User>
  end
end
```

Also see [this blog post](http://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup) which describes the same problem.